# Can I change jQuery.ajax's function call arguments (sent in data) through beforeSend event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dom-events

I have a code that goes something like this:

```
var offset = 1;
$.ajax({
    url: /www/loadmoredata,
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
        limit: 1,
        offset: offset
    },
    beforeSend: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        offset++;
    }
});
```

Now I would expect the offset passed through ajax to be 2, since I increment in `beforeSend`, which runs before the AJAX is processed. However, it seems that `beforeSend` increments the offset variable AFTER it has been appended as data to the function call.

My question is: am I doing something wrong or is this not what `beforeSend` method is meant to be used for? And if it isn't, what would be the right way to do what I intended?

Comment: What happens if you do `++offset`?

Comment: You've already passed the data object to the function, so it's too late to change the variables used in that object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correction, by the time beforeSend is called, the Request has already been constructed and the data object you are trying to change has been put into the Request. Here is the documentation for beforeSend http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ . The ajaxOptions parameter are not the options for the current ajax request. So you will be able to change the data you are passing into the request.

Maybe if you give us a higher level idea what you are trying to achieve we can help?

-- Original Suggestion --

Offset is still in scope, but your expectations are incorrect. Give this a try:

```js
var offset = 1;
$.ajax({
    url: /www/loadmoredata,
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
        limit: 1,
        offset: offset
    },
    beforeSend: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        ajaxOptions.data.offset += ajaxOptions.data.offset;
    }
});
```

Comment: Did you try this, or are you just assuming that the string stored in ajaxOptions can be changed, and that it would change the passed data as well ?

Comment: @adeneo I had not tried it. Right after I read my answer it did not sound correct. I have edited it.

Comment: I'll try it for you -> http://jsfiddle.net/g3MMy/ , and it does not seem to work !

Comment: Thanks @adeneo, I have amended my answer with links back to the reference documentation.

Comment: There really is no higher idea, I wanted to increment the variable offset before every AJAX request and thought it's what the beforeSend is for. What then is a practical usage for beforeSend and what would be the ideal way to increment the variable before every AJAX requesst?

Comment: I always create my own "Ajax" function that uses the jquery ajax function. That allows me to do things like keeping track of every ajax call I make to the server. I have used "beforeSend" to append headers to the http request. I'm sure there are other practical uses.